# How to swap two buttons' constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are two buttons named `buttonA` and `buttonB` in a same view, I have set their constraints in storyboard. How can I exchange their constraints programmatically?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exchange. Please explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for an answer of this and I ended up doing it in the following way:
(Code examples are in `Swift 3`)

Let's say you have a UIView called `containerView` which contains two UIViews: `subviewA` and `subviewB`.

The constraints for the subviews are actually defined within `containerView` (as per the rule of the "closest common ancestor").

This solution also assumes that the constraints have as a 'First Item' `subViewA` or `subViewB` and as a 'Second Item' `containerView`. If your setup is different you might need to modify the code accordingly.

So we have a function that swaps constraints:

```
private func swapFirstItemsOfConstraintsDefinedInThisView(_ superview: UIView, betweenItem item1: AnyObject, andItem item2: AnyObject)
{
    var constraintsToRemove: [NSLayoutConstraint]  = []
    var constraintsNew_item1: [NSLayoutConstraint]  = []
    var constraintsNew_item2: [NSLayoutConstraint]  = []

    for constraint in superview.constraints
    {
        if (constraint.firstItem === item1)
        {
            constraintsToRemove.append(constraint)
            constraintsNew_item1.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: item2, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: constraint.secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant))
        }
        else if (constraint.firstItem === item2)
        {
            constraintsToRemove.append(constraint)
            constraintsNew_item2.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: item1, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: constraint.secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant))
        }
    }

    superview.removeConstraints(constraintsToRemove);
    superview.addConstraints(constraintsNew_item1);
    superview.addConstraints(constraintsNew_item2);
}
```

So then you can call the following (in your `ViewController` somewhere):

```
self.swapFirstItemsOfConstraintsDefinedInThisView(self.containerView, betweenItem: subviewA, andItem: subviewB)
self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Note that the effects of the swap won't be shown unless you call the `layoutIfNeeded()`. Depending on your needs, you might want to add this call as the last line of the body of the swap function.

By the way if you call `layoutIfNeeded()` in an `UIAnimation` context (in the `animations` closure/block) it would animate the transition.

Note that there a lot of potential improvements of this code, it's just an example of the basic approach. For instance we could have an extension on `NSLayoutConstraint` to allow `init`ting it by copying another `NSLayoutConstraint` and changing only the 'First item' property (so that we avoid the long repeated lines of code above). Also the swap function itself could be defined in an extension of `UIView`. And performance-wise there are potential issues with the above implementation.

Comment: Hello, your code was very useful. However, I want item2 to completely replace item1. What actually happens is that item1 moves to the position of item1 and item1 moves a little towards the right, how can I stop that from happening? 

For reference, I'm building a card game which in which one card has to be placed right on top of the other card. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that by Xcode you meant at runtime with code.
Constraints items (`firstItem` and `secondItem`) are `readonly` properties (i.e.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/firstItem).

So you can edit them after creating them.

You could create two set of constraints for each button and activate/desactivate via their `active` property (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/active) the different set (which you can store in a `IBOutletCollection`) when desire.